# Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

Если обработка ввода пользователя происходит без преобразования в SQL-запрос, может произойти [внедрение SQL-кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332367/) в код приложения, например, как в следующем примере:

```php
$unsafe_variable = $_POST['user_input'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')");
```

Причина этому – пользователь может ввести любую цепочку символов, к примеру: `value'); DROP TABLE table;--`, и запрос приобретет следующий вид:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES('value'); DROP TABLE table;--')
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы такого не происходило?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/)» [@Andrew G. Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428190/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Используйте подготовленные операторы и параметризованные запросы.** Существуют SQL-выражения, которые отправляются и обрабатываются на сервере баз данных отдельно от параметров. Таким образом, злоумышленник не сможет внедрить вредоносный SQL-код.

В общем случае, у вас есть два способа достичь задуманного.

1. Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (для любого поддерживаемого драйвера баз данных):

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

2. Используйте [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (для MySQL):

```php
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Если база данных, к которой вы подключаетесь, управляется не MySQL, вы можете воспользоваться вторым вариантом (в зависимости от используемого драйвера, например, `pg_prepare()` и `pg_execute()` для PostgreSQL); универсальный вариант – PDO.

### Корректное установление соединения

Учтите, что при использовании `PDO` для установления соединения с базой данных MySQL *реальные* подготовленные операторы **по умолчанию не используются**. Чтобы исправить ситуацию, вам нужно будет отключить эмуляцию подготовленных операторов. Пример установления соединения с помощью PDO:

```php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

В приведенном выше примере режим обработки ошибок не является необходимым, но мы **настоятельно рекомендуем его использовать**. В этом случае при возникновении неполадок сценарий не остановится на `Fatal Error`. Также это дает разработчику шанс «отловить» ошибку (одну или несколько), которая вызывает исключение `PDOException`.

Тем не менее, **обязательным условием** здесь является строка `setAttribute()`, которая «говорит» PDO отменить эмулированные подготовленные операторы и использовать *реальные* подготовленные операторы. Это гарантирует, что как оператор, так и значения не анализируются PHP перед отправкой на MySQL-сервер (что не дает возможности злоумышленнику внедрить вредоносный код).

Вы, конечно, можете выбрать кодировку (`charset`) в опциях конструктора, но важно помнить, что «более старые» версии PHP (< 5.3.6) [просто игнорировали этот параметр](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) в DSN.

### Объяснение

Происходит следующее: SQL-оператор, который вы передаете, чтобы «подготовить», анализируется и компилируется сервером баз данных. Указывая параметры (`?` или именованный параметр типа `:name` в вышеприведенном примере), вы сообщаете механизму базы, где вы хотите произвести фильтрацию данных. После этого, когда вы вызываете `execute`, подготовленный оператор комбинируется с указанными вами значениями параметров.

При этом важно, что значения параметров комбинируются со скомпилированным оператором, а не с SQL-строкой. SQL-внедрение «обманывает» сценарий путем отправки в базу данных вредоносных SQL-строк. Поэтому посылая SQL отдельно от параметров вы уменьшаете риск получения неожиданного и нежелательного результата. Любые параметры, отправляемые при использовании подготовленного оператора, воспринимаются как строки (хотя, конечно, механизм базы данных может произвести определенную оптимизацию и параметры, в конце концов, могут быть преобразованы в численный формат).

В вышеприведенном примере, если переменная `$name` содержит `'Sarah'; DELETE FROM employees` результатом будет поиск строки
`"'Sarah'; DELETE FROM employees"`, а не [пустая таблица](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Еще одно преимущество использования подготовленных операторов – если один и тот же оператор исполняется много раз в течение одной сессии, он будет проанализирован и скомпилирован только один раз, что даст вам еще и оптимизацию в скорости.

Да, и поскольку вы спросили о том, как поступить с кодом инъекции, вот пример (используется PDO):

```php
$preparedStatement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:column)');

$preparedStatement->execute(array('column' => $unsafeValue));
```

### Можно ли использовать подготовленные операторы для динамических запросов?

Несмотря на то, что вы можете использовать подготовленные параметры в качестве параметров запроса, структура динамического запроса не может быть параметризована – равно как и некоторые особенности запроса.

Для таких особых сценариев лучше всего использовать фильтр «белый список», который будет ограничивать диапазон возможных величин.

```
// Value whitelist
// $dir can only be 'DESC' or 'ASC'
$dir = !empty($direction) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
```

<sub>Перевод ответа «[How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/564240)» [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109/theo)</sub>.