# Очистка URL от лишних символов

Tags: php

Пишу функцию для очистки url от всего лишнего, функция вынесена в отдельный файл:

```
<?php
    function clearString($cl_str){
        $cl_str = strip_tags($cl_str);
        $cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($cl_str);
        $cl_str = trim($cl_str);
        return $cl_str;
    } 
 ?>
```

Далее, уже в другом файле, я эту функцию вызываю:

```
<?php
    include("include/db_connect.php"); //подключение к БД
    include("functions/functions.php"); //Подключение непосредственно сабжа

    $cat = clearString($_GET["cat"]); 
    $type = clearString($_GET["type"]);
    $sorting = $_GET["sort"];

    include("include/sorting.php"); 
?>
```

Собственно, это всё на странице, где у меня реализован вывод товаров по категориям. Пытаюсь протестировать функцию - выбираю категорию товара (к примеру, Audi) и получаю сверху на странице такую ошибку:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\OpenServer\domains\autopartshop.ua\functions\functions.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\OpenServer\domains\autopartshop.ua\functions\functions.php on line 4
```

Лезу в документацию по mysqli_real_escape_string(), там пишется, что нужен еще параметр подключения к бд, я его вставляю этот $link и получаю это:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\OpenServer\domains\autopartshop.ua\functions\functions.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\OpenServer\domains\autopartshop.ua\functions\functions.php on line 4
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Покажите какое соединение вы передаете в функцию? Ясно же написано, что передаете null. У вас подключение в файле db_connect. Покажите что в нем

Comment: @Moonvvell вот содержимое коннекта:
    <?php
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_shop");
 if (!$link) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
 }
 mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
   ?>

Comment: Приведите весь ваш код в вопросе. Вы написали что вставляете линк в функцию. Из вашего вопроса этого не видно. Ваша функция `clearString`, к примеру, должна тогда принимать два параметра, соединение и саму строку

Comment: @Moonvvell я имею в виду, что в функции clearString я добавляю $link первым параметром в функцию mysqli_real_escape_string(), то есть выглядит она таким образом:
$cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cl_str);

Comment: @Dremjke, вы занимаетесь ерундой используя такую функцию clearString(). Вам нужно использовать подготовленные выражение при запросах к БД. А вывод введенных пользователем данных делать через htmlspecialchars().

Comment: @Vismanу меня нету здесь выводе введённых пользователем данных. Функция clearString нужна для того, чтобы очищать url от лишних символов при непосредственных запросах к БД (в данном случае - при выводе из БД товаров по категориям)

Comment: @Dremjke, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511895/186083

Comment: @Visman спасибо большое, буду изучать материал. Однако, вопрос с ошибкой остаётся открытым...

Comment: решили данную проблему ? точь в точь как у вас, ошибки те же выдает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php запись mysqli_real_escape_string в процедурном стиле выглядит так:

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

где **$link - идентификатор соединения, полученный с помощью mysqli_connect()**,
а $escapestr - строка, которую вам нужно экранировать.

Если компилятор ругается, что передаете null - скорее всего вы передаете пустую переменную.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь разобрался и всё работает :)
В файл functions.php в функцию clearString первой строкой я добавил $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_shop"); и теперь всё работает!)

Comment: @Dremjke осталось только понять, какой смысл вызывать здесь mysqli_real_escape_string, которая НИЧЕГО НИ ОТ ЧЕГО не "очищает". Не говоря уже о целиком бессмысленной функции clearString