# Ошибка mysqli: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php

Вот такое выдает:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/nfwhrbvo/public_html/functions/functions.php on line 7

Седьмая строка выглядит так:

```
$cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($cl_str);
```

Comment: [вот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/664228/191482)

Comment: Научись читать ошибки. Хотя бы банально закинь в переводчик текст и прочитай.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , промахнулся ответом. После разголосования проголосовать уже нельзя?

Comment: @br3t да я тоже в начале промахнулся)) уже нельзя переголосовать. Кажется около недели. Наверное пусть останется. Как раз с подходящим заголовком, чтоб остальные закрывать как дубли

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка URL от лишних символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663997/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-url-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @Visman там есть ответ, но по заголовку вообще не в тему. И тело вопроса там жесть. Много воды и не по делу.. Может этот вопрос как раз и оставить чтоб дублем крыть остальные?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ответ я дополнил. На сколько удачно оформил, не знаю. Дубликат снял.

Comment: Алексей,в первую очередь в переводчик кссстессно в засунул.только мне это ничего не дало.не работаю с php,поэтому сюда и обратился.Вот так бывает,представляете!?Сразу нельзя ответ написать,хоть наводку.а не умника включать?))))

Comment: @АндрейАкимов перейдя по ссылке в первом комментарии можно увидеть ответ. Также, смею заметить, можно увидеть ответ если просто открыть документацию PHP и конкретно страницу с описанием метода `mysqli_real_escape_string`  http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) должна вызываться с двумя параметрами (*процедурный стиль*):

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

где

**link**
Идентификатор соединения, полученный с помощью `mysqli_connect()` или `mysqli_init()`

**escapestr**
Строка, которую требуется экранировать. Экранируемые символы *NUL* (*ASCII 0*), *\n*, *\r*, **, *'*, *"*, и *Control-Z*.

Comment: Что тут из ответа мне приходится.я не понимаю.какте-то новые слова!Кто-нибудь что-нибудь вразумительное может дать по КОНКРЕТНО моему вопросу ,с моим примером связанное?????

Comment: @АндрейАкимов серьезно? ты не понимаешь?

Comment: @АндрейАкимов вы вызываете функцию с одним параметром, а надо с двумя.

Comment: ПОВТОРЯЮ-я не связан с php! Кто-нибудь знает здесь,что КОНКРЕТНО я должен добавить в свою седьмую строчку?
$cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($cl_str);
На это поменять?$cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli $link, $cl_str); ??? не помогает

Comment: @АндрейАкимов у вас там где-то в коде должна вызываться функция `mysqli_connect()` или `mysqli_init()`, и ее результат присваивается какой-то переменной. Часто это выглядит как `$db = sqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db")`. Но переменная может называться как угодно: $db, $link, $connection или как-то еще.  Вам нужно ее найти и подставить первым параметром: `$cl_str = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $cl_str);` Повторюсь:  переменная может называться и не `$db`. Вам нужно ее найти в коде  самому.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.вот теперь ясно как божий день.Спасибо.

Comment: У меня она называется $link,но подставив спереди,ничего не произошло.подскажите,пожалуйста,еще что-нибудь....хоть один нормальный коммент