# Фильтр поиска на php

Tags: php

как лучше реализовать фильтр поиска на php
Вот как получилось у меня

```
if(isset($_GET["name"]))
{
    $name = htmlentities(stripslashes($_GET['name']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $t[] .= "(name LIKE '%$name%' OR text LIKE '%$name%')";
}
if(isset($_GET["tags"]))
{
    $tag = htmlentities(stripslashes($_GET['tags']), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $t[] .= "(tags LIKE '%$tag%')";
}
if($t)
{
    $d = "WHERE";
    $t = implode(" AND ", $t);
}
else
{
    $d = "";
}

$rezult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product $d $t");
```

И простая форма, все в принципе работает, хотелось бы узнать о корректности кода и может есть более простой способ

Comment: Посмотрите на предупреждение разработчиков в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php P.S. `htmlentities(stripslashes(...` не поможет, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511895/186083

Comment: @Visman а я немного разожгу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482  ))

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Comment: как по мне так лучше интегрировать поисковый движок типо sphinx или строить полнетокстовый поисковый индек

Comment: [`mysqli`](https://upread.ru/art.php?id=227) - более современное и куда более безопасное расширение для PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уж не использовать mysqli подобный код я бы написал примерно так:

```
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$tag    = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tags']);

$_GET['name'] ? $t[].= "(name LIKE '%$name%' OR text LIKE '%$name%')" : false;
$_GET['tags'] ? $t[].= "(tags LIKE '%$tag%')" : false;

$rezult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product ".($t ? "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $t) : false ));
```