# MYSQL PHP экранирование символов

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой код:

```
   "MATCH (" . $field . ") AGAINST ('" . 
addslashes(str_replace(array('(', ')', '-', '*', '"'), null, $txt)) . " *' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Какие есть встроенные PHP функции, чтобы отказатся от замены `str_replace`, и не перечислять каждый символ?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: чтобы писать код не как 15-10 лет назад лучше вообще на PDO перейти и использовать параметреризованные запросы

Comment: Используйте подготовленные выражения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/186083 И если вам нужно, чтобы символы `()-*"` искались как символы, а не использовались как управляющие конструкции запроса, то используйте addcslashes() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addcslashes.php Но подготовленные выражения в запросах ни кто не отменяет!