# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (id_staff, table_number, ord, datat) VALUES ($staff,$numbtable,$order,now())";
```

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема

Comment: как предположение - `$staff,$numbtable,$order` оберните в кавычки каждое значение

Comment: одна из переменных пуста, либо является строкой, которая содержит запятую

Comment: Да, были запятые, спасибо. Кавычки помогли

Comment: @Grai, как правильно вставлять переменные в запросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/186083