# Подготавливаемые запросы MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, preparedstatement

Доброго времени суток !

Есть `sql` запрос:

```
$gPlaceholderName = $mysqli->query("SELECT `gPlaceholderName` FROM `gData` WHERE `gID` = '$gID'");
```

Помогите составить подготавливаемый запрос и объясните как ими пользоваться и в будущем их составлять самому.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Уважаемый @KirillKorushkin, я ознакамливался с этой документацией, но с практикой проблемы, мне бы один пример для моего случая, а дальше пойму. Я еще не все тонкости построений sql запросов знаю. Много ужасов про sql инъекции узнал.

Comment: @tonymore в мануале SELECT и у вас SELECT, в мануале подставляется один параметр в WHERE и у вас (разве что тип bind_param другой). В мануале подробные комментарии написаны... Если их вам не хватает, то как поможет точно такой же пример с точно таким же запросом но другим наименованием таблицы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, блин, допер теперь, просто я не замечал объяснения функции bind_param и не понимал что означала и откуда там бралась буква для задающего типа !

Comment: @tonymore  Вы копнули немного не туда. Если вы прежде всего обеспокоены безопасностью запроса, тогда вам необходимо экранировать(обрабатывать тело и проверять тип) передаваемые значения. Функций для этого в пхп достаточно и знать их в любом случае придётся. Подготовленный вопрос в данном случае конечно решает вопрос безопасности почти полностью, но задачи у него другие.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, а подготавливаемые запросы экранируют символы ?

Comment: @tonymore  нет, их экранирует сервер (см. док-цию). http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @tonymore просто обрабатывайте данные перед вставкой в запрос и будет вам щастье. Т.е. вы чётко должны знать, что у вас ложится в запрос до того, как оно там окажется. А prepare используйте, если количество одинаковых запросов в бд больше двух.

Comment: @tonymore ознакомьтесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/143035/ (комменты тоже читайте), это необходимо знать в любом случае. Успехов!

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, спасибо большое, понял !

Comment: @KirillKorushkin не надо ерунду писать.... подготовленные выражения вполне себе позволяют нормально всё сделать и 100500 методов обработок и фильтрации не нужны... не надо сбивать с толку людей, особенно статьёй **2012**-го года (можно было еще на php 4.6 сразу))).....проверять нужно например на корректность, например, чтобы не ввели отрицательный год рождения к примеру

Comment: @tonymore По поводу защиты - Не смотрите советы KirillKorushkin - это бред.....достаточно устанавливать **правильное соединение**, отключить эмуляцию запросов и спокойно использовать подготовленные выражения. В принципе об этом можно попробовать посмотреть тут: [Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/191482) и в ответах тут [Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/191482) (там есть выводы о том что нужно)

Comment: @tonymore хотя совсем четкий вывод есть в конце вот этого ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/6104996 ... Почитайте................................`просто я не замечал объяснения функции bind_param и не понимал что означала и откуда там бралась буква` - да, в мануале в принципе написано "Метки параметров должны быть связаны с переменными приложения функциями mysqli_stmt_bind_param() и/или mysqli_stmt_bind_result() до запуска запроса или выборки строк" и если перейдете в http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  посмОтрите какие бывают типы. Этого будет ясно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский эмуляция, вроде, это про PDO, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Как подготовить и выполнить SQL запрос ?

---

Для того чтобы подготовить и выполнить SQL запрос нужно:

- Подготовить запрос
- Выполнить привязку переменной к параметрам
- Выполнить запрос

#### Подготавливаем запрос

Функция `prepare` подготавливает SQL выражение к выполнению.

*Примечание: Ниже представленный пример выполнен в Объектно-ориентированном стиле*

```
$gPlaceholderName = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `gPlaceholderName` FROM `gData` WHERE `gID` = ?");
```

#### Привязываем переменную к параметру

За привязку переменных к параметрам отвечает функция `bind_param`.

```
$gPlaceholderName->bind_param("i", $groupID);
```

Буква `i` означает тип integer.

Ниже описаны часто используемые параметры:

- `i` - соответствующая переменная имеет тип integer
- `d` - соответствующая переменная имеет тип double
- `s` - соответствующая переменная имеет тип string

#### Выполняем запрос

`execute` отвечает за выполнение SQL запроса.

```
$gPlaceholderName->execute();
```

#### Послесловие

Вся представленная информация взята с официальной русской документации [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Также хотел поблагодарить [Алексея Шиманского](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и [Кирилла Корушкина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236197/kirill-korushkin) за наставление на путь истинный.