# Php сервер не вносит данные в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Возникла следующая проблема: php сервер не вносит данные в бд с помощью СУБД mysql. Отладку кода делал, значения в переменных правильные, но данные не записываются, подскажите, что делать.

Код:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$binding = $_POST['binding'];
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$login = trim($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$password = trim($password);
$binding = stripslashes($binding);
$binding = htmlspecialchars($binding);
$binding = trim($binding);
$mail = strpos($binding, '@');
$tel = strpos($binding, '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0');
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO accounts (login, password, mail, phone) VALUES('$login', '$password', '$mail', '$tel'");
```

Comment: Добавьте в описание, что выводит `echo mysqli_error($db);`

Comment: Причём отдельно после mysqli_connect, отдельно после mysqli_query. А также покажите, какая получается строка запроса после подстановки в неё значений переменных.

Comment: Ошибка: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @ИванРепин А вот нефиг пихать параметры в SQL. Используйте preparedStatements

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/186083

Comment: @Visman Ну и закрывай сразу этим дубликатом