# Транслит при вносе данных в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть необходимость вносить данные в БД на русском но, чтоб в таблицу они попадали уже транслитом на латинице

при таком написании кода функция не выполняется.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO category (category,alt_image)
    VALUES(
    '".$_POST[ftranslite("form_category")]."',
    '".$_POST["form_alt_image"]."'
    )
    ",$link);
```

и при таком тоже :)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO category (category,alt_image)
    VALUES(
    '".ftranslite($_POST["form_category"])."',
    '".$_POST["form_alt_image"]."'
    )
    ",$link);
```

Comment: Читайте почему у вас ни чего не работает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/186083 + функции `mysql_` отсутствуют в современном php.

Comment: А что за функция `ftranslite`, какой запрос получается в итоге, какой код ошибки возвращается.....

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

давай правлиние конфигураци database

Comment: Вы выбрали неправильные кодировку и сравнение.