# не отправляется запрос в бд

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli, cms

первый файл(update_category.php)

```
<?php
         if(isset($_POST['update_category'])) {
           $new_cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];
           $query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '{$new_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$update_cat_id}";
           $update_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
           if(!$update_query) {
             echo "Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection);
           }
         }
          ?>
```

второй файл

```
if(isset($_GET['update'])) {
                          $update_cat_id = $_GET['update'];
                          include "update_category.php";
                        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Не, у меня совсем другое. Я делаю свою CMS. Не думаю, что админ будет sql инъекции делать)

Comment: Все что я скинул - это часть панели админа

Comment: `Не думаю, что админ будет sql инъекции делать`, а не надо так думать, это неправильный подход.

Comment: В любом случае, я прохожу курс на Udemy, поэтому весь этот код написан по моим пройденным там урокам. До sql инъекций я еще не дошел, поэтому и пишу криво. Понимаете, это не реальный проект, а просто отработка пройденного материала.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое Udemy. И если они так преподают, уча плодить дыры в безопасности, то и не хочу знать.

Comment: Можете загуглить. Udemy - онлайн платформа, где каждый человек может стать учителем, а его курс покупают или получают бесплатно обычные пользователи. В любом случае я не планирую на этом останавливаться. Это так, для общего развития. Потом хочу закрепить книгой дмитрия котерова. Кстати, вы читали?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, существуют ли реально `$_POST['update_category']` и `$_GET['update']`.

Сделайте правки на запрос с подготовленным выражением ([prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'UPDATE categories SET cat_title = ? WHERE cat_id = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sd', $new_cat_title, $update_cat_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Да, я проверил. Существуют. Я вообще по курсу на udemy занимаюсь.Там вроде также сделано, но у меня где-то ошибка

Comment: @Visman, согласен. Внес правку. Спасибо за замечание