# Не получается редактировать запись в базе данных под средство sql запросов ошибок не выдает на apache и xdebug

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) //проверяем, есть ли переменная на удаление
    {
        $sql = $link->query("DELETE FROM shop WHERE ID = ".$_GET['del_id'].""); //удаляем строку из таблицы по ID
    }

    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) //Проверяем, передана ли переменная на редактирования
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['title']) or !empty($_POST['description']) or !empty($_POST['price']) or !empty($_POST['image']) or !empty($_POST['cat']))
        {
            $title=htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
            $description=htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
            $price=htmlspecialchars($_POST['price']);
            $image=htmlspecialchars($_POST['image']);
            $cat=htmlspecialchars($_POST['cat']);

            if (!empty($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $sql = $link->query("UPDATE shop SET 
                `title`='".$title."',
                `description`='".$description."',
                `price`='".$price."',
                `image`='".$image."',
                `cat`='".$cat."'
                 WHERE ID = ".$_GET['red_id']."
                 ");
                if (!$link){die('updating error'. mysql_error());} else {echo 'updating error'. mysql_error($link);}
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        }
    }
?>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Название продукта</td>
    <td>Описание продукта</td>
    <td>Цена продукта</td>
    <td>Картинка продукта</td>
    <td>Категория продукта</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = $link->query("SELECT ID,title,description,price,image,cat FROM shop WHERE ID");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$result['ID'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$result['title'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$result['description'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$result['price'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$result['image'].'</td>'.
    '<td>'.$result['cat'].'</td>'.
    '<td><a href="?del_id='.$result['ID'].'">Удалить</a></td>'.
    '<td><a href="?red_id='.$result['ID'].'">Редактировать</a></td></tr>';
}

?>
</table>

<?php

    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) //Если передана переменная на редактирование
    {
        //Достаем запись из БД
        $sql = $link->query("SELECT ID,title,description,price,image,cat FROM shop ORDER BY ID ='".$_GET['red_id']."'"); //запрос к БД
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql); //получение самой записи


?>
<table>
<form action="Deleteproduct.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>Название продукта </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="<?php echo ($result['title']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Описание продукта</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description" size="50" value="<?php echo ($result['description']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Цена продукта</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price" size="10" value="<?php echo ($result['price']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Картинка продукта</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="image" size="15" value="<?php echo ($result['image']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Категория продукта</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cat" size="15" value="<?php echo ($result['cat']); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <p><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="OK">
        <input type="button" value="Отмена" onclick=" location.href='index.php'">
        <input type="button" value="Назад" onclick="location.href='Admin.php'"></center></td></p>
    </tr>

</form>
</table>
    }
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: SOS SOS SOS SOS SOS SOS

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Запросы трешовые. После каждого `$sql = $link->query(..)` делайте проверку `if (!$sql) die(mysql_error(...))`

Comment: or die ('ERROR : '. mysqli_error($sql)); не помогает

Answer (score 0):

так попробуй

```
 if ((!empty($_POST['title'])) or (!empty($_POST['description'])) or
 (!empty($_POST['price'])) or (!empty($_POST['image'])) or 
 (!empty($_POST['cat'])))
```

Comment: Не помогло if ((!empty($_POST['title'])) or (!empty($_POST['description'])) or
 (!empty($_POST['price'])) or (!empty($_POST['image'])) or 
 (!empty($_POST['cat'])))

Comment: <?php
 //include ('connection.php');
    $host="localhost"; //хост
    $dbusername="root";  //пользователь
    $dbpassword="ghjuhtcc";//пароль
    $db_name="neo"; //название бд
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $link= mysqli_connect ($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$db_name) or die ('$db_name : NO_DB_SELECT');//коннектимся
?>