# Защищают ли кавычки от sql-инъекции?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Скажите пожалуйста, защищает ли кавычки от sql-инъекции.
У меня есть такие коды

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `kredits` FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = '$mail' AND `password` = '$pass'");

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO  `vivod` (`summa`, `email`) VALUES ('$zsum', '$summal')");
```

Защищены ли они от sql-инъекции? И если нет то `mysqli_real_escape_string` может защищать?

Comment: нет, не защищают. используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php и забудьте кавычки и escape как страшный сон

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не защищают. Попробуй так:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //тут свои данные подставь
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `kredits` FROM `users` WHERE `mail` = ? AND `password` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password); //s-string
$stmt->execute();
```

Ну и вот [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-stmt.php)