# Шанс sql инъекции и как её избежать?

Tags: sql, frontend, backend

Делаю сайт, суть которого заключается в турнирах (dota) с призовым фондом. Не разбираюсь пока ни в sql, ни в sql инъекциях. Где-то слышал, что провести такие инъекции может любой колхозный дурачок, если сайт не защищен.

Так вот: я собираюсь баланс аккаунта держать в sql. Каким образом вообще могут туда попасть, каким образом изменить значение и каким образом от этого защищаться?

Сервер на php.

Comment: А на сервере какие запросы в базу отсылаете?

Comment: На чем написан бэкенд? И каким образом он принимает запросы?

Comment: php. Никаких запросов еще не отправлял, потому и спрашиваю - каким образом могут прикопаться в бд.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Не вижу в этом топике ответы на вопросы "Как и каким образом могут попасть ко мне в БД?", спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, на чем написан backend(тонкости использования БД)

Помощь в гугле ищи по запросу "основы SQL"

Если используешь php, то почитай про PDO, RedBeanPHP(на любителя)

Если ты будешь работать с реальными деньгами, то советую сначала понять основы SQL, почитай статью https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/310726/ (там 4 части)