# Не записывает данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно, пришёл с таким вопросом, почему не проходят данные в БД? Как ни пробовал, убирал одинарные кавычки, обычные, ставил даже там где не нужно, ничто не помогло.

Вот сама правка в БД:

```html
$query="INSERT INTO `registr_users` (`id`, `date_created`, `login`, `password`, `email`)
                  VALUES (NOW(), '$login', '$password', '$email')";
```

Ответ при вводе в SQL:

## 1136 - Количество столбцов не совпадает с количеством значений в записи 1

Comment: Отож... 5 полей, и всего 4 значения...

Comment: _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в запрос. _Всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые запросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511895/194569 Это поможет как избежать массы проблем при разработке и отладке, так и защитит ваши сайты от взломов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и есть), 1136 - Количество столбцов не совпадает с количеством значений в записи,
у тебя должно точно совпадать количество и очередность значений!
попробуй так.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `registr_users` (`login`, `password`, `email`)
                  VALUES ("'.$login.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$email.'")";
```

Comment: Получилось, однако, " и . вывело как ошибка в синтаксисе, так что пришлось убрать. Но тут еще одна проблемка, теперь скрипт просто бесконечно грузит...

Answer (score 0):

> просто бесконечно грузит.

; - конец запроса:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `registr_users` (`login`, `password`, `email`)
                  VALUES ("'.$login.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$email.'");";
```

Comment: Тоже самое, хотя при вводе в SQL уже добавляет.