# Не будет ли проблем, если есть 2 соединения к БД на одной странице

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть несколько вопросов.

1. Не будет ли проблем, если 2 соединения к БД на одной странице?
2. Не нужно их разрывать/завершать и т.п.? Один и тот же пользователь часто будет загружать/открывать данную страницу снова.
3. И вообще, корректно написан код или можно лучше?

```
$firstname= 'name'; 
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email); 
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name='{$firstname}'");
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) )
{     
    echo $row['id']; 
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['bln'];
}

//////  

$id= 2; 
$query = "UPDATE users SET bln=bln-10 WHERE id=".$id."";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: Ну, в показанном вами коде соединение `$mysqli` одно-единственное

Comment: А вот то, что вы [не совсем правильно защищаетесь от SQL-инъекций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896), уже немножко грустно

Comment: я новичок, не удивляйтесь.    $mysqli->query($query); вы об этом ?

Comment: А с чего бы им быть, проблемам-то? соединения же полностью независимы, соединению глубочайше похрен, единственное оно или рядом есть ещё парочка. Главное - смотри не перепутай.

Comment: Говорю же, я пару дней назад начал интересоваться mysql, спрашиваю  по этому у тех, кто опыт за плечами имеет

Comment: про корректность кода почитайте про передачу параметров, подготовленные выражения и sql-инъекции

Comment: а что с sql inject , взломать могут или о чем речь ?

Comment: @MASOriginal Да и не только взломать. У вас же сверху есть пример запроса, так и второй сделайте таким же - `$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET bln=bln-10 WHERE id='{$id}'")`. В случае, если данные будут откуда то подтягиваться, например, с Ajax, то тогда нужно делать экранирование по ситуации.

Comment: У вас одно соединение с БД. Разрывать соединения не нужно, они закроются сами при завершении работы php. Код написан плохо, но про это уже сказали.

Comment: @sousage1212 ок, переделаю, тогда косяк с sql инъекции отпадёт как я понял?